# How to scale each node, represented as a pie chart, in a graph on mouse over using D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, mousehover, graph-visualization

I'm working a graph visualization in **D3** where each node represents a person working on multiple projects collaborating with multiple people. So, I customized the nodes as pie charts where portions of pie charts represents % of time the person is allocating for different projects. The radius of the pie varies based on some weight given to each node.

Due to this varying radius some nodes are so small that one cannot see them as pie charts. So, I wanted to create a mouse over effect that can magnify a node on hovering mouse over it. **My intention is not to animate each portion of a pie but to animate whole pie chart as if it is a simple circle.**

The code that I added to animate the arcs of the hovered pie chart is not working. When I hover on a node I'm getting below error

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNA12.80000…".
(anonymous) @ d3.v3.min.js:5
a @ d3.v3.min.js:3
Rn @ d3.v3.min.js:1
Tn @ d3.v3.min.js:1
```

Here is the code snippet that I have -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000000;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      stroke-opacity: 0.8;
    }

    div.tooltip {   
        position: absolute;         
        text-align: center;
        min-width: 100;
        width: auto;    
        min-height:25;
        height: auto;                   
        padding: 2px;               
        font: 10px sans-serif;      
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #fff;
        border: 0px;        
        border-radius: 8px;         
        pointer-events: none;           
    }

</style>
<body bgcolor="#A9A9A9">
<script type="text/javascript">
    graph = { "nodes":[{"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 1}, 
                                        {"group": 2, "value": 2}, 
                                        {"group": 3, "value": 3}],"Weight": "2","name":"abc1"},
                       {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 2}, 
                                        {"group": 2, "value": 1}, 
                                        {"group": 3, "value": 5}],"Weight": "3","name":"abc2"},
                       {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 7}, 
                                        {"group": 2, "value": 1}, 
                                        {"group": 3, "value": 3}],"Weight": "4","name":"abc3"},
                       {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 5}, 
                                        {"group": 2, "value": 3}, 
                                        {"group": 3, "value": 4}],"Weight": "2","name":"abc4"},
                       {"proportions": [{"group": 1, "value": 2}, 
                                        {"group": 2, "value": 7}, 
                                        {"group": 3, "value": 3}],"Weight": "1","name":"abc5"}],
              "links":[{"source": 0, "target": 1, "width": 1},
                      {"source": 1, "target": 2, "width": 1},
                      {"source": 1, "target": 3, "width": 1},
                      {"source": 2, "target": 3, "width": 1},
                      {"source": 0, "target": 2, "width": 1},
                      {"source": 4, "target": 2, "width": 1}]
            }

    var width = 960,
        height = 500,
        radius = 25,
        color = d3.scale.category10(),
        rscale = d3.scale.linear().range([5,20]);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius)
        .innerRadius(0);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-90)
        .gravity(0.09)
        .distance(100)
        .size([width, height]);

    force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();

    rscale.domain(d3.extent(graph.nodes,function(d){ return d.Weight; }))

    var div = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
            var hoverArc=d3.svg.arc()
                    .outerRadius(50)
                    .innerRadius(0);

            d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                .duration(250)
                .attr("d", hoverArc);

            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(d.name)   
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
            })
        .call(force.drag);

    node.each(function(d){
        arc = arc.outerRadius(rscale(d.Weight));

        d3.select(this)
        .selectAll("path")
            .data(function(d) {return pie(d.proportions); })
        .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(d.data.group); });
    });

    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'; });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope the above sample helps to give an idea of what I'm dealing with. I would highly appreciate any help that puts me in right direction, I'm still a novice in D3.

Comment: Can you upload on jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bkkale/5zxnphjb/) to jsfiddle.

Comment: Before giving the answer I'd like to confirm just one thing. You want to disable this thing that disappear the blue arc and want to add the zoom feature. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want to do. I know how to disable this disappearance of blue arc but I don't have any clue on how to add the zoom feature.

Comment: There's something weird. If I change the outerRadius it doesn't take effect unless you change innerRadius... I don't have time right now, but I'll reorganize your code later.

Comment: I saw your force layout question on Google Groups on how to not waste screen space. Here’s something relevant: http://www.smartjava.org/content/voronoi-fractal-d3js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `select`, it has to be `selectAll`:

```
d3.select(this).selectAll("path").transition()
    .duration(250)
    .attr("d", hoverArc);
```

Because `this` is a group element and all the paths in a given pie are children of that group.

Here is your updated code:

```js
graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "proportions": [{
      "group": 1,
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "group": 2,
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "group": 3,
      "value": 3
    }],
    "Weight": "2",
    "name": "abc1"
  }, {
    "proportions": [{
      "group": 1,
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "group": 2,
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "group": 3,
      "value": 5
    }],
    "Weight": "3",
    "name": "abc2"
  }, {
    "proportions": [{
      "group": 1,
      "value": 7
    }, {
      "group": 2,
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "group": 3,
      "value": 3
    }],
    "Weight": "4",
    "name": "abc3"
  }, {
    "proportions": [{
      "group": 1,
      "value": 5
    }, {
      "group": 2,
      "value": 3
    }, {
      "group": 3,
      "value": 4
    }],
    "Weight": "2",
    "name": "abc4"
  }, {
    "proportions": [{
      "group": 1,
      "value": 2
    }, {
      "group": 2,
      "value": 7
    }, {
      "group": 3,
      "value": 3
    }],
    "Weight": "1",
    "name": "abc5"
  }],
  "links": [{
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "width": 1
  }, {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2,
    "width": 1
  }, {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 3,
    "width": 1
  }, {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 3,
    "width": 1
  }, {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 2,
    "width": 1
  }, {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 2,
    "width": 1
  }]
}

var width = 600,
  height = 400,
  radius = 25,
  color = d3.scale.category10(),
  rscale = d3.scale.linear().range([5, 20]);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .innerRadius(0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-90)
  .gravity(0.09)
  .distance(100)
  .size([width, height]);

force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

rscale.domain(d3.extent(graph.nodes, function(d) {
  return d.Weight;
}))

var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var hoverArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(50)
      .innerRadius(0);

    d3.select(this).selectAll("path").transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("d", hoverArc);

    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    div.html(d.name)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {

    var hoverOutarc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(rscale(d.Weight))
      .innerRadius(0);

    d3.select(this).selectAll("path").transition()
      .duration(250)
      .attr("d", hoverOutarc);

    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })
  .call(force.drag);

node.each(function(d) {
  arc = arc.outerRadius(rscale(d.Weight));

  d3.select(this)
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(function(d) {
      return pie(d.proportions);
    })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(d.data.group);
    });
});

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  });
});
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-opacity: 0.8;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 25;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I just have one followup question. If I use only select (as in my previous code), atleast the current path of the pie chart has to be updated with given radius. Why was it not working and making the arc disappear?

Comment: It has to do with the "datum" passed to the arc generator. Using `select` you're not passing the correct datum, and your path gets a lot of `NaN`s.

Comment: Ok. Just to understand, if I want to apply the same zooming effect to only the specific arc on which mouse is hovered and not to entire circle, what changes should I make?

Comment: Your question makes little sense: you're calling the "mouseover" on the group, not on the paths.

Comment: hmm.. Understood your point. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I tried adding some more animations. Now, I have added "mouseover" event on each of the path elements on the group and tried to animate each of them with much higher outer radius but I couldn't see the effect as expected. here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bkkale/5zxnphjb/). What am I missing here?